# 2W laser diode driver

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, laser-diode

I'm trying to use a [Thorlabs L1450G1 IR Laser diode](https://www.thorlabs.com/drawings/a7b649c4b090f810-0BA90030-0C1D-D73F-B61E7588336177D3/L1450G1-SpecSheet.pdf). I built a circuit that a friend made (I think it is for another model.) It does not work.

Supposedly this circuit controls and varies the current to get different output powers.
Every other tutorial that I've found works with less current or output power.
I'm attaching the specs of the laser diode I have and the circuit.

[image]

I measured the voltage between P$1 and P$2.  It was 5V without the laser and 0.7V when the laser was connected. The specificatiions say that it needs 1.4V and 520 mA (which I don't know how to measure.)

I have the components specified in the diagram so, if it is possible, I'd prefer to keep using them but I'm also open to go grab other things. Can you help me?

[image]

Comment: *It does not work.* <-- measure all node voltages and use paint or equivalent to put them on the schematic.

Comment: R3 is too large; it can't sink 520mA unless it gets the entire 5V supply. 1 Ohm should just about do it.

Comment: R3 will need to be capable of a fairly high power.  With 500 milliamperes through it and  a couple or three volts across it, it'll have to dissipate at least one watt, maybe two.

Comment: Hi JRE. Wont the diode use them?

Comment: There should be about 1.4V across the diode.  That leaves 3.6V across the resistor and the MOSFET.  The 500mA has to flow through the MOSFET and the resistor.  At 3.6V and 500mA, that's 1.8 watts of power.  It will be dissipated in the resistor and the MOSFET - how much in each is not easy to predict.  Regardless, a little SMD resistor won't work - it'll probably go up in smoke.  You'll need something capable of the full power.

Comment: Oh. Crap.   500mA is only the threshold current.  At 2 watts output power it will be drawing 5A of current.  You'll need to look at getting a real shunt resistor made for 5A or more rather than playing with standard resistors.

Comment: What output power do you want (maximum)?

Comment: Just a note that 2W *output* power will put you deep into class IV territory and that it is not just possible, but easy to permanently blind yourself in a fraction of a second, all the more so since the beam is invisible and will not trigger a blink or any other aversion response (at class IV, your blink reflex is too slow anyways).  Beam traps and laser safety goggles *rated for the wavelength and output power* you are using are absolutely essential.

Comment: Hi RuseellH. I think that 1W would be more than enough.

Hi vir. Yes, I'm having a lot of optical cautions and using beamdumps to beware of this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> *The specifications say that it needs 1.4V and 520 mA*

Well, you need to change components because to get 520 mA through the 10 Ω source resistor requires it to be at 5.2 volts i.e. higher than the supply voltage. Let me suggest that you lower R3 from 10 Ω to something like 2.2 Ω to see if there's an improvement. Adjust the pot back to zero and gradually raise it checking for anything overheating along the way.

Answer (score 0):

You can measure the current through the diode by measuring the voltage across either R3 or R4. Since R3 is being used to set diode current, it makes sense to measure that. Using Ohm's law:

$$ I_{DIODE} = \frac{V_{R3}}{R_3} $$

The op-amp is controlling the voltage across R3 to be exactly equal to the potential applied to its non-inverting (pin 3) input, and it is this "reference" potential (I'll call it \$V_{REF}\$) which is then responsible for setting the exact current through the diode, according the above equation.

By adjusting R5, you can produce any reference voltage \$V_{REF}\$ between 0V and

$$ V_{REF(MAX)} = 5V \times \frac{R_5}{R_5+R_1} = 5V \times \frac{10k}{10k + 68k} = 0.64V $$

This means that the maximum voltage you can expect across R3 is 0.64V, for a maximum current of:

$$ I_{MAX} = \frac{V_{REF(MAX)}}{R_3} = \frac{0.64V}{10\Omega} = 64mA $$

That's lower than you require, so you'll need to change R3 to obtain whatever maximum current you intend to ever pass through the diode. Again using Ohm's law, and knowing that the maximum voltage across R3 is 0.64V:

$$ R_3 = \frac{V_{REF(MAX)}}{I_{MAX}} = \frac{0.64V}{I_{MAX}} $$

For example, let's say you want to be able to produce between 0A and 1A through the diode, depending on the position of R5, corresponding to a potential \$0V < V_{REF} < 0.64V\$. You must set R3 to a value which would pass 1A when 0.64V is across it:

$$ R_3 = \frac{0.64V}{1A} = 0.64\Omega $$

As another example, if you set \$R_3 = 0.33\Omega\$, the maximum current you can obtain through the diode is:

$$ I_{MAX} = \frac{0.64V}{0.33\Omega} = 1.9A $$

Beware of power dissipation in R3 (and R4, and Q2!). For example, if you set \$R_3 = 0.33\Omega\$, at maximum current of 1.9A, R3 and R4 will dissipate:

$$ P_{R3} = I^2R_3 = 1.9^2 \times 0.33\Omega = 1.2W $$

$$ P_{R4} = I^2R_4 = 1.9^2 \times 1\Omega = 3.6W $$

Make sure your components can all handle the heat!

Answer (score 0):

As JRE pointed out, for operating at 2W the diode requires 5A.

At 5A, \$R_4\$ will drop 5V, The entire supply voltage. 520mA is the threshold current where the diode begins to light up.

\$R_3\$ at 5A will drop 50V. So these two resistors must be lower to achieve the output power that the diode is capable of.

Andy and Simon have given good technique and information.

The diode needs 1.4V, the transistor needs enough voltage to allow regulation. That leaves little voltage left for \$R_3\$ and \$R_4\$.

An example (not a recommendation):
\$R_3=0.56\Omega\$ sets the input voltage to a maximum of 1V for 5.6A of current.

\$R_4=0.47\Omega\$ limits the current to less than the maximum diode current.(In case the potentiometer is turned up to high.